# subprocess communicate is left hanging

Tags: python, subprocess, hpc

I have a fortran code that accepts a single input. I have successfully run this program on my computer. I am now trying to run it on the login node of an HPC cluster. On the login node, the subprocess is left hanging by the communicate. I know that my subprocess is sensible as if I make my fortran code run without any manual input I can make the Popen run fine.

```
import subprocess

dirPath="/mypath"
p=subprocess.Popen(["./myprogram"],shell = False,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,cwd=dirPath,encoding="utf-8")
p.communicate(input="000000")
```

I would be very grateful for any advice to fix or bypass this problem

Comment: And when you run the program outside of Python (just in a shell) with the same arguments, does the program itself hang?

Comment: I'm not sure, but `myprogram` probably expects you to press Enter to submit the input, but `p.communicate` probably doesn't do that for you, so you can try adding the newline symbol at the end of the input string.

Comment: You are right ForceBru, thank you. But the interesting thing is that communicate worked with spaces instead of tabs on my computer but hanged on the HPC system.